# Llamar a funcion javascript desde un string

Tags: javascript

En mi base de datos tengo como string la función a ejecutar y en otro campo los parámetros que se envían a dicha función, las funciones ya están declaradas con su respectivo valor de retorno como podria llamarlas desde mi string?

Es decir:

```
funcionUno=function(val){
  return "Hola 1"+val;
}

funcionDos=function(val){
  return "Hola 2"+val;
}

var EjecutarFuncion="funcionUno";
var enviarParametro="Stack";
```

He intentado:

```
var result= new Function(EjecutarFuncion)(enviarParametro);
console.log(result);
```

pero obtengo undefined

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cualquier función es también un método del objeto window.

```js
funcionUno=function(val){
  console.log ("Hola 1 "+val);
}


window["funcionUno"]("Rastalovely");
```

Comment: muchas gracias ...

Answer (score 0):

Dado que mi codigo corre del lado del servidor no es posible usar window, lo solucione de la siguiente manera:

```js
funcionUno=function(val){
  return "Hola 1 "+val;
}

funcionDos=function(val){
  return "Hola 2 "+val;
}

var EjecutarFuncion="funcionUno";
var enviarParametro="Stack";

let func = new Function('return ' + EjecutarFuncion)();
var dato=func(enviarParametro);
console.log(dato);
```

Answer (score 0):

Existe una respuesta mucho mas global y completa para esta pregunta, la cual fue respondida por el usuario Jason Bunting en el siguiente link: [How to execute a JavaScript function when I have its name as a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/359788/how-to-execute-a-javascript-function-when-i-have-its-name-as-a-string)

Debido a que esta respuesta esta en inglés, voy a traducir el contenido:

---

No utilizar la función `eval`, al menos que estes 100% seguro que no tienes otra alternativa.

Como ha sido mencionado, utilizando algo similar sería la mejor manera de realizarlo:

```
window["functionName"](arguments);
```

Sin embargo, esto no funcionará cuando la función utiliza namespaces:

```
window["My.Namespace.functionName"](arguments); // fallará
```

De a siguiente manera se debe ejecutar:

```
window["My"]["Namespace"]["functionName"](arguments); // funcionará
```

Con el fin de hacerlo mas fácil y proveer flexibilidad, a continuación se presenta una función para resolver esto:

```
function executeFunctionByName(functionName, context /*, args */) {
  var args = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 2);
  var namespaces = functionName.split(".");
  var func = namespaces.pop();
  for(var i = 0; i < namespaces.length; i++) {
    context = context[namespaces[i]];
  }
  return context[func].apply(context, args);
}
```

Con el código anterior, podrás ejecutar la función de la siguiente manera:

```
executeFunctionByName("Mi.Namespace.nombreDeFuncion", window, argumentos);
```

El segundo parámetro es el contexto en el cual se ejecuta la función, la cual puede ser modificado de acuerdo a sus necesidades:

```
executeFunctionByName("Namespace.nombreDeFuncion", Mi, argumentos);
```